# Check S3 availability check / Ping from SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, amazon-s3, ssis

I am creating a New SSIS Job, and i want add a step to check S3 bucket availability before starting import Job. we are using Zappysys to connect S3.

I tried ZS Amazon S3 Storage task --> Storage Action: Get Amazon container exist status, but no luck

SSIS availability check step should handle the error with an alert and failure when validations fails

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass the result of the check to a variable. 
Further, the value of the variable should be handled in the **Event Handlers** section, using **OnVariableValueChanged** handler by some scripts that will log the value/stop the execution/etc.